# 32 bit mantissa representation of 2455.1152

Tags: binary, 32-bit, fixed-point

If I wanted to represent -2455.1152 as 32 bit I know the first bit is 1 (negative sign) but I can get the 2455 to binary as 10010010111 but for the fractional part I'm not too sure. .1152 could have an infinite number of fractional parts. Would that mean that only up to 23 bits are used to represent the fractional part? So since 2445 uses 11 bits, bits 11 to 0 are for the fractional part?

for the binary representation I have 10010010111.00011101001. Exponent is 10. 10+127=137. 137 as binary is 10001001.

full representation would be:

1 10001001 1001001011100011101001

is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to devise your own floating-point representation, but you used a fixed-point tag so I will explain how to convert your real number to a traditional fixed-point representation. First, you need to decide how many bits will be used to represent the fractional part of the number. Just for the sake of discussion let's say that 16 bits will be used for the fractional part, 15 bits for the integer part, and one bit reserved for the sign bit. Now, multiply the *absolute value* of the real number by 2^{16}: 2455.1152 * 65536 = 160898429.747. You can either round to the nearest integer or just truncate. Suppose we just truncate to 160898429. Converting this to hexadecimal we get 0x09971D7D. To make this negative, invert and add a 1 to the LSB, and the final result is 0xF668E283.

To convert back to a real number just reverse the process. Take the absolute value of the fixed-point representation and divide by 2^{16}. In this case we would find that the fixed-point representation is equal to the real number -2455.1151886 . The accuracy can be improved by rounding instead of truncating when converting from real to fixed-point, or by allowing more bits for the fractional part.